# When not to call FlushAsync on IAsyncCollector in Azure Functions ServiceBus binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a range of Azure Function apps all outputting messages to Azure Service Bus using the `IAsyncCollector<Message>`:

```cs
public async Task Run([ServiceBus(...)] IAsyncCollector<Message> messages)
{
    ...
    await messages.AddAsync(msg);
}
```

I'm getting errors logged from time to time looking like this:

```cs
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Function
 ---> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusTimeoutException: The operation did not complete within the allocated time 00:00:59.9999536 for object message.Reference: ..., 7/13/2020 2:46:24 PM
 ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation did not complete within the allocated time 00:00:59.9999536 for object message.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.SendingAmqpLink.EndSendMessage(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.OnSendAsync(IList`1 messageList)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.OnSendAsync(IList`1 messageList)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageSender.SendAsync(IList`1 messageList)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Bindings.MessageSenderExtensions.SendAndCreateEntityIfNotExists(MessageSender sender, Message message, Guid functionInstanceId, EntityType entityType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at My.Function.Run(String mySbMsg, IAsyncCollector`1 messages)
```

I'm having a bit of a hard time figuring out when in the pipeline this happens. But I have recently learned about the `FlushAsync` method:

```cs
await messages.AddAsync(msg);
await messages.FlushAsync();
```

My question is the following. Why would I ever NOT include a call to `FlushAsync` in my function? Getting the timeout exception in my own code will make it possible to retry, do better exception logging, and more. Any downsides of flushing manually like this within the function code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why would I ever NOT include a call to FlushAsync in my function? Getting the timeout exception in my own code will make it possible to retry, do better exception logging, and more.

I'm going to go a bit further here and say that after I earned some experience with Azure Functions, I now avoid `IAsyncCollector<T>` completely. Some implementations publish on `AddAsync`; other implementations may publish on both `AddAsync` and `FlushAsync`. I suspect the service bus implementation is actually publishing on `AddAsync`, in which case `FlushAsync` may be a noop.

The nice part about `IAsyncCollector<T>` is that it gives you a "write these things" abstraction; all you have to do is provide a connection string, and the rest is magic. The problem with `IAsyncCollector<T>` is that it gives you an abstraction, and thus you have much less control.

Under the hood, how many retries are being done? Are they using constant delays or exponentially increasing? What's the behavior if it never succeeds? Usually none of this critical information is documented.

What's especially annoying is when the AF team *changes the semantics* of the abstraction. E.g., for some of the output bindings (either CosmosDB or storage, I don't remember), the retry behavior changed from one release of the functions SDK to the next.

So, I've gravitated towards avoiding output bindings, especially `IAsyncCollector<T>`. I usually want to do tight but exponentially increasing de-correlated jittered retries with a cap of a minute or so, but aborted when there's only a minute left of Functions runtime, and then the recovery behavior changes to writing a message to an error queue (with retries). This is way more complex than an `IAsyncCollector<T>` could ever provide, but it isn't that hard to do with Polly calling the SDKs directly.

> Any downsides of flushing manually like this within the function code?

No. By default, `IAsyncCollector<T>.FlushAsync` is called by the functions host after your function executes. So if you call it yourself, you're just calling it early. It should be safe to call multiple times.

Comment: That's a great suggestion actually. A feature like retry is something I have had a hard time figuring out if included or not in each binding. Sometimes I've even ended up in situation  where I have wrapped a retrying call in Polly which caused too many retries.

Comment: @ThomasArdal retrying call in Polly  sample ?

Comment: Please use a new question to ask how to use Polly.

Comment: There's the following open issue around [driving consistency of batching behaviour with the IAsyncCollector](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/921)

Comment: Stephen, maybe a dumb question but can you avoid input bindings also when they are triggers? For example, a Service Bus trigger? I don't see how you could avoid it, but I also don't understand the mechanism that makes this work... that is, is the feature to trigger a function based on a SB message only available via an input binding or is there one or more alternative ways to configure this (perhaps via json settings, or in Startup code?) without actually having to use an input binding?

Comment: @BVernon: input bindings and trigger bindings are different. Are you wanting a trigger binding?

Comment: Not sure I understand... in the case of service bus the trigger *is* also an input binding. I guess what I'm asking is whether it's possible to have a function that's triggered by a service bus message but without the input binding so that you can write your own code to get the messages.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with calling `FlushAsync` in your code. The current implementation of `IAsyncCollector` for the ServiceBus output binding is that your messages get batched until `FlushAsync` is called or the function returns. When trying to send a high volume of messages I stumbled on the same Timeout exception as you. The solution I found is to call `FlushAsync` every N messages, in my case `N=100` was the best trade-off. Calling `FlushAsync` too often would trigger obvious performance penalties.